# Javascript normalizing string

Tags: javascript, json, string, normalization

So I have to parse a search string to later generate a JSON object from it.

Sample inputs

```
"Amercian01 SFO2016"
"Amercian 01 SFO 2016"
"Amercian-01 2016SFO"
"Amercian:01 SFO16"
```

Outputs for all these strings should return

```
{
airline: "American",
flightNo: 01,
airport: "SFO",
year: "2016"
}
```

Code

```
var str = "Amercian-01 2016SFO";
document.write(str.split(/[ :-]+/));
```

It will output American,01, 2016SFO

2 questions:
1) How would I split 2016SFO into 2016, SFO
2) Is this the best approach?

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pdubey84/msebk5a2/

Comment: Ok. Did you have a question?

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry but I pressed send too quickly and I thought I had pasted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code snippet with working example:

```js
getNormalizedData('American01 2016 SFO');
getNormalizedData('Amercian 01 SFO 2016');
getNormalizedData('American-01 SFO2016');
getNormalizedData('Amercian:01 SF0-2016');

function getNormalizedData(str) {
  var airline = str;
  var flightNo = "";
  var airport = "";
  var year = "";
  var airlineEndMatch = str.match(/[ \d\-\:]/);
  if (airlineEndMatch) {
    airline = str.substr(0, airlineEndMatch.index);
    str = str.substr(airlineEndMatch.index);
    if (!str[0].match(/\d/))
      str = str.substr(1);

    var flighNoEnd = str.indexOf(" ");
    flightNo = str.substr(0, flighNoEnd);
    str = str.substr(flighNoEnd);
    airport = str;
    var yearMatch = str.match(/\d{4}/);
    if (yearMatch) {
      year = yearMatch[0]
      airport = (airport.replace(year, ""))
        .trim()
        .replace("-", "");
    }
  }

  var flight = {
    airline: airline,
    flightNo: flightNo,
    airport: airport,
    year: year,
  }

  console.log(flight);
}
```